# Phonegap : How to make every page load

Tags: cordova

I am building an app in Phonegap framework and I want on each page need to load upon call other function.
Let's say I have the homepage with a menu. When user enter on 'page2' to call page2_function(),on enter 'page3' to call page3_function();
Markup structure :

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="c">
            <!-- Header -->
            <div data-role="header" id="wrap-header">

                   <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"/>
                   <a href="page2" class="menu" data-transition="slide">page2</a>
   <a href="page3" class="menu" data-transition="slide">page3</a>
             </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <!-- Content    -->
            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e" id="list_view"></ul>
                <h3>Content</h3>
                <p>
                    page1
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <!-- footer -->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>&copy; 2013 Your Name</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
  <!--page2-->


 <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="c">
                <!-- Header -->
                <div data-role="header" id="wrap-header">

                       <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"/>
                       <a href="page2" class="menu" data-transition="slide">page2</a>
       <a href="page3" class="menu" data-transition="slide">page3</a>
                 </div>
                <!-- /header -->
                <!-- Content    -->
                <div data-role="content" id="content">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e" id="list_view"></ul>
                    <h3>Content</h3>
                    <p>
                        page1
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- /content -->
                <!-- footer -->
                <div data-role="footer">
                    <h4>&copy; 2013 Your Name</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- /footer -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem :

```
function page1_function() {
 location.reload();
 //Your code goes here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery mobile page events as follows:

```
$(document).on("pagechange","#page1", function (event) {
     //Function called on pagechanged
});
```

**Note:**

The **pagechange** event can be any page event based on timing you want to execute the function

[Jquery mobile page events](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: I use this function but no alert <br> $(document).on("pagechange","#page2", function (event) {
     alert('page loaded');
});

Comment: the above snippet is an example to how to hock jquey mobile page to an event. 

did you try **pageload** event ?